# powershell select-object outputs array on one line

Tags: powershell

I have around 20 arrays which contain over 100 values each.

I want to output these to a csv file with column headings.

If I type any of these arrays in a powershell command prompt they display on multiple lines and I can select different items from the array using `$arrayname{14]` for example, so I think they are being stored correctly.

If I use the following line in my script:

```
"" | select-object @{Name="Column1"; Expression={"$Array1"}},@{Name="Column2"; Expression={"$Array2"}},@{Name="Column3"; Expression={"$Array3"}} | export-csv $exportLocation -notypeinformation
```

Then it creates the columns with the heading but each array variable is displayed on one line.

How can I get the output to display the arrays in the respective columns on a line of their own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your 4 arrays into an array of objects with 4 properties. Try this:

```
$Array1 = @(...)
$Array2 = @(...)
$Array3 = @(...)
$Array4 = @(...)

$len1 = [Math]::Max($Array1.Length, $Array2.Length)
$len2 = [Math]::Max($Array3.Length, $Array4.Length)
$maxlen = [Math]::Max($len1, $len2)

$csv = for ($i=0; $i -lt $maxlen; $i++) {
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    'Column1' = $Array1[$i];
    'Column2' = $Array2[$i];
    'Column3' = $Array3[$i];
    'Column4' = $Array4[$i];
  }
}

$csv | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Unfortunately its not outputting anything. The arrays hold the following commands: 

$Array1 = @(dsget group "CN=OU1,OU=Departments,OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com" | dsquery user -limit 1000)
$Array2 = @(dsget group "CN=OU2,OU=Departments,OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com" | dsquery user -limit 1000)
$Array3 = @(dsget group "CN=OU3,OU=Departments,OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com" | dsquery user -limit 1000)
$Array4 = @(dsget group "CN=OU4,OU=Departments,OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com" | dsquery user -limit 1000)

Comment: @user2615378 My bad. I didn't fix all variable names after I copy/pasted my code. Please try again.